# Can someone help me simplify this trig expression?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> $$( \tan x+ \sec x )( \cot x-\cos x ) $$

I got stuck after a few steps of converting and adding and what not.

Comment: The correct answer should be csc(x) - sin(x)

Answer (score 5):

Let $a = \tan x$ and $b = \sec x$; then the expression is equal to

$$\left(a + b\right)\left(\frac 1 a - \frac 1 b\right) = 1 + \frac b a - \frac a b - 1 = \frac b a - \frac a b$$

Now note that $\frac 1 a = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ and $\frac 1 b = \cos x$ to finish the simplification.

Answer (score 1):

A simplification:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( \tan x + \sec x \right) \left( \cot x - \cos x  \right) &= \left(\tan x + \frac{1}{\cos x} \right)\left( \frac{1}{\tan x } - \cos x\right) \\
&=\frac{\tan x}{\tan x}-\cos x \tan x +\frac{1}{\cos x \tan x}-\frac{\cos x}{\cos x} \\
&=1-\cos x \tan x +\frac{1}{\cos x \tan x}-1 \\
&= \frac{1}{\cos x \tan x}-\cos x \tan x \\
&= \frac{\cos x}{\cos x \sin x}-\frac{\cos x \sin x}{\cos x} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sin x}-\sin x \\
&= \csc x - \sin x.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The correct answer should be csc(x) - sin(x).

Comment: I deleted my latter lines to stop at your desired result. It is difficult to guess at what simplified form one wants. For example, $\cot x \cos x$ is an equivalent simplification. Had you mentioned this on your original post I would not have have gone further.

Comment: Sorry haha, that's my fault. Still learning pre calc here. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :). Do tell if anything is less than perfectly clear, and best of luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

$$( \tan x+ \sec x )( \cot x-\cos x )=\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}\frac{\cos x(1-\sin x)}{\sin x} $$

if $\cos x\ne0,$ this becomes $$\frac{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}=\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\sin x}=\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin x}$$

I was expecting something more interesting :)